# How to track changes in a property stored in Vuex(store) and perform some method based on the value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, properties, vue-component, vuex

I'm trying to change the links based on the variable user_role which is stored in Vuex(store). I'm not able to find an appropriate way to track the change and based on its value I want to perform some method. Any suggestions on how to do it?

```
------------------------------store.js-------------------------------
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user_role: "User"
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
});




-----------------------------------component.vue---------------------------


export default {
  name: "Navbar",
  data() {
    return {
      links: [
        { text: "Projects", route: "/projects" },
        { text: "Requests", route: "/requests" },
        { text: "", route: "" },
        { text: "Resources", route: "/resources" }
      ],
      pers_actions: ["Profile", "LogOut"],
    };
  },
  watch: {
    user_role: {
      if (user_role === "PM") {
        this.links[2] = {
          text: "Allocations",
          route: "/allocations"
        };
      } else if (user_role === "PMO") {
        this.links[2] = {
          text: "Reports",
          route: "/reports"
        };
      } else if (user_role === "User") {
        this.links = [
          {
            text: "Allocations",
            route: "/allocations"
          }
        ];
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than explicitly mutating your local data in response to some state change, it is better to compute your links within a computed property because it will automatically update whenever some dependent data has changed. It'll "just work".

```js
computed: {
  links() {
    switch (this.$store.state.user_role) {
      case: "PM": return [
        { text: "Projects", route: "/projects" },
        { text: "Requests", route: "/requests" },
        { text: "Allocations", route: "/allocations" },
        { text: "Resources", route: "/resources" },
      ];

      case: "PMO": return [
        { text: "Projects", route: "/projects" },
        { text: "Requests", route: "/requests" },
        { text: "Reports", route: "/reports" },
        { text: "Resources", route: "/resources" },
      ];

      // For any other role
      default: return [
        { text: "Allocations", route: "/allocations" },
      ];
    }
  }
}
```